# Umbraco Courier Upgrade

Tags: umbraco7

I have an Umbraco project with Umbraco.Courier.Package.v2.50.1.171 installed.

The package needs to be upgraded to Courier.v2.52.0

Is there a best practice to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Go to https://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/umbraco-courier-2/ and follow the instructions to install the hotfix.